# How can I find impending gotchas from the leap second being added in July

Tags: java, .net, time, leap-second

A leap second will be added to the calendar on July 1st this year.
I am concerned that there could be impending ramifications to our application stack, that we would like to preempt.

The Wikipedia article, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second lists some past gottchas but none of them relate to my applications.

What should we be looking for to prevent armageddon?